# Device Access Console - The project could not be created

Tags: nest-device-access

I am attempting to integrate my NEST devices with Home assistant so following these instructions: https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/nest/

I have created a google cloud project, enabled "Smart Device Management" and "Cloud Pub/Sub" APIs, configured OAuth Consent screen which is now in production and configured OAuth Application Credentials - which generated a client ID and Secret.

I have also paid the $5 for the device access console so can access this screen:
[image]

However when I go through the process of creating a project, inputting the OAuth Client ID and submitting, it will try for a few minutes and then get the following error:

[image]

Really not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well and I finally figured it out.

After spending more time than I care to admit on it, I realized I could create a project if I skipped the "OAuth Client ID" step. I was then able to go into the project and add the Client ID from there.

What happened is that I had been copy/pasting the Client ID directly from the Google Cloud Console. For some reason, **copy/pasting directly from Google Cloud Console adds extra spaces to the start and end of the Client ID string.** After I got rid of the extra spaces, I could create projects as expected.

I wish the errors were more descriptive.

Comment: This worked for me and should be considered a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same thing. I don't think it's you. The endpoint to actually create the project is returning a 503-Service Unavailable response. Likely a temporary issue.

Comment: As another commenter suggested, logging out and back in seems to resolve, as in the project seems to appear.

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering an issue as well
Marko seems to have discovered that it is on them right now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue yesterday. This morning I logged out of the Drive Access Console and then logged back in with the same gmail account and my project was there.

Comment: That was my experience. Seemed a mixture of impatience on my part and something not working on their end.